# SQL FTS and comparison statements

Tags: sql, sqlite, fts4

Short story. I am working on a project where I need to communicate with SQLite database. And there I have several problems:

There is one FTS table with *nodeId* and *nodeName* columns. I need to select all nodeIds for which nodeNames contains some text pattern. For instance all node names with "Donald" inside. Something similar was discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501805/using-fts-query-can-you-find-all-entries-contains-abc). The point is that I can't use *CONTAINS* keyword. Instead I use *MATCH*. And here is the question itself: how should this "Donald" string be "framed"? With '*' or with '%' character? Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM nodeFtsTable WHERE nodeName MATCH "Donald"
```

Is it OK to write multiple comparison in *SELECT* statement? I mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM distanceTable WHERE pointId = 1 OR pointId = 4 OR pointId = 203 AND distance<200
```

I hope that it does not sound very confusing. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Sorry, I missed the fact that you are using FTS4.  It looks like you can just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM nodeFtsTable WHERE nodeName MATCH 'Donald'
```

[Here is relevant documentation.](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)

No wildcard characters are needed in order to match all entries in which `Donald` is a discrete word (e.g. the above will match `Donald Duck`).  If you want to match `Donald` as part of a word (e.g. `Donalds`) then you need to use `*` in the appropriate place:

```
SELECT * FROM nodeFtsTable WHERE nodeName MATCH 'Donald*'
```

If your query wasn't working, it was probably because you used double quotes.

From [the SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match()
>   application-defined function. The default match() function
>   implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for
>   anything. But extensions can override the match() function with more
>   helpful logic.

FTS4 is an extension that provides a `match()` function.

Yes, it is ok to use multiple conditions as in your second query.  When you have a complex set of conditions, it is important to understand the order in which the conditions will be evaluated. `AND` is always evaluated before `OR` (they are analagous to mathematical multiplication and addition, respectively).  In practice, I think it is always best to use parentheses for clarity when using a combination of `AND` and `OR`:

```
--This is the same as with no parentheses, but is clearer:
SELECT * FROM distanceTable WHERE 
    pointId = 1 OR 
    pointId = 4 OR 
    (pointId = 203 AND distance<200)

--This is something completely different:
SELECT * FROM distanceTable WHERE 
    (pointId = 1 OR pointId = 4 OR pointId = 203) AND
    distance<200
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case LIKE is unacceptable - it will take too many time to find necessary entries.

Comment: @besworland, sorry, my first answer was mistaken.  Please see the edited version.

Comment: Thank you. But will I get back all the entries with "Donald" in this case? In this document it is written that '*' must be placed somewhere in a phrase?

Comment: @besworland, no wildcards are needed as long as you want to match `Donald` as a separate word.  Please see the clarification in the answer.

Comment: Exactly, here is the point, I want all the words with Donald. It can be McDonald's or DonaldDuck or whatever.

Comment: @besworland, then you should use `'*Donald*'`

Comment: Can you give me any tips for my second question?

Comment: @besworland, sorry, I had mentioned that, but I accidentally deleted it when editing the question.  I have updated it again and given more detail.